# rewrite url using mod rewrite without redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this url is being rewritten

```
http://domain.com/embed/slideshow-image-list.js
```

to this

```
http://domain.com/code/embed/slideshow-image-list
```

current htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^embed/([^\.]+)\.js$ http://domain.com/code/embed/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

its currently rewritten correctly, but if you visit the .js url it redirects to the full url.

im looking just to map it without redirection

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't supply the domain in the rule, just the path. With the full domain it will be redirected.

`RewriteRule ^embed/([^\.]+)\.js$ /code/embed/$1 [L]`

Alternately, if the resulting path is not a real file and should be handled by index.php, stip off the `[L]` so that the next rule will be executed:

`RewriteRule ^embed/([^\.]+)\.js$ /code/embed/$1`

Note that the [mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says the following, which would seem to indicate that the full URL path is okay, but I believe it compares against ServerName, not necessarily ServerAlias (I'm not 100% sure about that, but I've always used paths rather than full URLs in doing non-redirect rewrites):

> Absolute URL
>
> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see the [R] flag below.

Comment: Oh, you'll probably need to remove the `[L]` if the `/code/embed/slideshow-image-list` isn't an actual file and is supposed to be handled by index.php via the following rules.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the previous comment and to add a note from the Apache documentation.

Comment: combination of things yours fixed it, but it was also a codeigniter issue, had to change a variable for the uri_protocol, thanks.

Comment: "Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL" - missed that important info in the docs :-/

Comment: what if I want to use the old path and just change the url ? for example I have a file called /test.php and when it's accessed I want the url to be /test but it should load the same file (/test.php)