# Rewrite two parameters without redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have tried to follow: [rewrite url using mod rewrite without redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420597/rewrite-url-using-mod-rewrite-without-redirection)
Without success so far.

I have a domain with a directory like this:

```
domain.com/sub/
```

I want to allow these URL options to navigate each:

```
domain.com/sub => domain.com/sub/index.html?p1=&p2=&full=
domain.com/sub/ => domain.com/sub/index.html?p1=&p2=&full=
domain.com/sub/NUMBER => domain.com/sub/index.html?p1=NUMBER&p2=&full=
domain.com/sub/NUMBER/ => domain.com/sub/index.html?p1=NUMBER&p2=&full=
domain.com/sub/NUMBER1/NUMBER2 => domain.com/sub/index.html?p1=NUMBER1&p2=NUMBER2&full=
domain.com/sub/NUMBER1/NUMBER2/ => domain.com/sub/index.html?p1=NUMBER1&p2=NUMBER2&full=
domain.com/sub/NUMBER1/full => domain.com/sub/index.html?p1=NUMBER1&p2=&full=full
domain.com/sub/NUMBER1/full/ => domain.com/sub/index.html?p1=NUMBER1&p2=&full=full
```

/sub/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/full(/)*?$ index.html?p1=$1&p2=&full=full
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)(/)*([0-9]*)(/)*?$ index.html?p1=$1&p2=$3&full=
```

Comment: What rules have you got so far ?

Comment: Your rules work on my side (I just added a `/sub` in the pattern to match where I put them on my side). What don't work on your side ? For that error, what say the logs ? You can also activate the debug logs for the rewrite module ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2, [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4).

Comment: Thank you David Duponchel for making me better sure i was right.
For anyone else who wants to know, I had to add this line to top of the head of the index.html file:

<script> window.history.replaceState(null,"","/sub/");</script>
And this was solved.