# htaccess url rewriting with multiple php vars in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rewriting

I need to create friendly urls for my website

need to change this url:
[http://sitename.com/pn?title=1100متر+ویلایی+گلابدره&id=117](http://sitename.com/pn?title=1100%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B1+%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C+%DA%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%87&id=117)

to this url, that contains utf-8 characters to
[http://sitename.com/1100متر+ویلایی+گلابدره](http://sitename.com/1100%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B1+%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C+%DA%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%87)
I also need my variables like id, by using htaccess rewriting can i stil use them ?
is there a good doc that i can learn more about url rewriting ?
and is url rewriting good for website seo ?

THANKS

Comment: You just want to show this new url or want to redirect to new url?

Comment: i only want to change the urls name, not redirecting them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this, I am unsure about the character you are passing and also you need to pass id in url too for rewriting. Please let me know if it works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([\d]+)$ pn?title=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: i test it, and it worked, but urls become like: http://kolbex.com/خوابگاه+برادران+صدرا/157           can i do somthing that if url was http://sitename.com/pn?title=1100متر+ویلایی+گلابدره&id=117 it become http://sitename.com/1100متر+ویلایی+گلابدره automaticlly , i mean i don't want to have http://sitename.com/pn?title=1100متر+ویلایی+گلابدره&id=117 anymore ..

Comment: But you don't want to pass id to page please clarify!

Comment: of course i need to pass id to the page, i just need have a friendly url, this : kolbex.com/خوابگاه+برادران+صدرا/157 is great but my images and css won't load

Comment: So if you are passing id to page you need to specitfy in url like sitename.com/12 <- this is id, in your case after your title you need to pass id too /117 and for css and javascript use this tag in your head section `<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/" >`

Comment: thanks it worked, but stil some css files won't load

Comment: I hope you put your website name here `href="http://www.w3schools.com/"` instead of w3schools.com i forgot to explain this.

Comment: i didn't put it on top of the page, my bad - you have +1 thanks man ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```js
var currentURL = window.location.href;
var currentDomain = window.location.hostname;
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
window.history.pushState('page',document.title,getParameterByName('title'))
```

Comment: this code only change the url after page loads, i need i have a friendly urls - i believe need to using htaccess

Comment: may be this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420597/rewrite-url-using-mod-rewrite-without-redirection#answer-14421187