# How to rewrite url in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a redirect code this one:

```php
 header("Refresh: 5; url={$_GET['url']}"); 
 echo 'You are redirecting to ... page';
```

It works when I add any external URL at the end like this:

```
http://my-domain.com/URL.php?url=
```

This just redirects to an external domain, in this case, let's use Google as the external URL:

```
http://my-domain.com/URL.php?url=http//www.google.com
```

It just redirects directly on the page after 5 seconds but I want to change the URL format to something like these:

```
http://my-domain.com/URL.php?http//www.google.com
http://my-domain.com/?http//www.google.com
```

Comment: try with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: i want to rewrite url sir :|

Comment: please be more precise on what you want exactly. Tutorials on url rewriting are quite long. With your present question, i could answer "take a text editor and rewrite your URLs", it would globally answer it..

Comment: Does this solve the problem?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420597/rewrite-url-using-mod-rewrite-without-redirection

Comment: @VickyMalhotra Kaddath's comment answers your question. Try it.

Comment: @ceejayoz i tried but nothing happened!

Comment: @JustCarty yes similiar problem with me but in my case i wanted to make rewrite rule :|

Comment: @VickyMalhotra Have you even read the suggested answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421187/3578036

Comment: yeah and i tried too, i added a .htaccess file in my webdirectory and added some code like `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-domain.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^embed/([^\.]+)\.php$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule URL.php /` But still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) like so:

```php
$url = "http//my-domain.com/?http//www.google.com";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
echo $query; // outputs "http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: i actually want this script to work for all domain not only for google

Comment: ok, so i don't understand the question.
He need a rewrite rule like this may be ? 
    RewriteRule URL.php / [L]

Comment: @Samy yes, do you know how?

Comment: I don't know what you want exactly but you can try this website
http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=24edad8b-bfba-56d1-9fa9-7c2fac27c9b3

Comment: alright i got it, this can be done with .htaccess file using rewrite code but don't know how to do it can anyone help me?