# Rewrite URL without Redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite some of my paths on my website. I don't want to redirect, just simply modify the URLS. This is what I have attempted so far based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420597/rewrite-url-using-mod-rewrite-without-redirection):

```
RewriteRule ^thankyou.html /thankyou/$1 [L]
```

However, all this is doing is redirecting to my homepage. I have several paths I would like to rewrite globally. But I figured I would test it first on my `/thankyou.html` page to get it working. So in this example, I am just trying to rewrite `example.com/thankyou.html` to `example.com/thankyou`.

Here is the full `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^thankyou.html /thankyou/$1 [L]


<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

 # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # Fonts
  ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

I've done this in the past on AWS Amplify using JSON which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "source": "https://www.example.com/thankyou.html",
        "target": "https://www.example.com/thankyou",
        "status": "301",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

But unfortunately, this web app is not hosted on amplify and I am struggling to find an equivalent.

Comment: You should really state in natural language exactly what you are trying to do, since the rule you've posted does not really make sense.

Comment: So I have *example.com/thankyou.html* and I would like to re-write the URL to *example.com/thankyou* with the `.html` omitted. I have other URLs I want to rewrite as well. An example would be to take *example.com/sub/doc.php?gm_code=pd01* and rewrite it to something more simple like *example.com/newpath* ... hope that is clear.

Comment: It looks like you are using the term "re-write" incorrectly. It makes no sense to internally rewrite the URL like that. It sounds like you are wanting to actually "change" these URLs - which requires more than just `.htaccess`. _Aside:_ Are the "old/existing" URLs (eg. `thankyou.html`) established - are they indexed by search engines or linked to/bookmarked by third parties?

Comment: Note that the _rule_ you posted includes a trailing slash (ie. `/thankyou/`) which is what I've carried through in my answer. However, you are using `/thankyou` (no trailing slash) in your description. You will need to modify the rule accordingly, since these are two different URLs.

Comment: "I've done this in the past on AWS Amplify using JSON" - The JSON you posted would appear to trigger a 302 (external) redirect from `/thankyou.html` to `/thankyou` (no trailing slash). This is not a "rewrite" and wouldn't make sense in this context. You would need to implement additional rules (rewrites) to rewrite the request back to `/thankyou.html` (the underlying file that actually handles the request). At the end of the day... **#1** What is the desired canonical URL? **#2** What is the underlying file that actually handles this request?

Comment: @MrWhite I accidentally used a `302` example when I meant to show a `301` example. It's been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^thankyou.html /thankyou/$1 [L]
> ```

If the underlying file is `thankyou.html` then you have the rewrite the wrong way round. You should be rewriting the request from `/thankyou/` (which I assume is the intended canonical URL) to `/thankyou.html`. And consequently you should be requesting (linking to) the URL `/thankyou/` in your HTML source.

*Aside:* The `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string is superfluous. It is always empty in this example.

In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^thankyou/$ thankyou.html [L]
```

The slash prefix on the *substitution* string is not required for internal rewrites (and best omitted).

Note that since the URL-path also matches the file basename, you need to ensure that MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) is also disabled, otherwise your rule is essentially bypassed (which could result in problems later). At the top of the `.htaccess` file you should add:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

---

**UPDATE:**

It sounds like you are expecting the URLs to magically change in the HTML source by doing the above. This is not the case and not the purpose of `.htaccess`. To change the URLs your users see (ie. the canonical URL), you must actually change the URLs you are linking to in the HTML source - there is no shortcut to this if this is an otherwise static site.

If the "old" URLs (ie. `/thankyou.html`) are established and indexed by search engines and/or linked to by external third parties then you can also include an external 301 redirect from `/thankyou.html` to `/thankyou` in order to preserve SEO. But note that this is not essential for your site to function, since you should have already changed the URLs in the underlying HTML source. It *is* necessary for SEO.

If you don't change the URL in the HTML source (and still implement the "redirect") then users can still "see" the old URL on the page (when they hover over or "copy" the link) and every time they click the link they are externally redirected (doubling the number of requests to the server and potentially slowing your users).

For example:

```
Options -MultiViews

# Redirect from "/thankyou.html" to "/thankyou" for SEO
RewriteRule ^thankyou\.html$ /thankyou [R=301,L]

# Rewrite from "/thankyou" to "/thankyou.html"
RewriteRule ^thankyou$ thankyou.html [END]
```

Note the addition of the `END` flag on the second (rewrite) rule.

Note also that I have removed the trailing slash on the URL. So, `/thankyou` is the URL you should be linking to and `/thankyou.html` is the underlying file that handles the request.

Comment: Do you mind opening a chat where I can explain further? Otherwise, I have explained a bit more in my comment and also edited the question with some more details. Thank you.

Comment: My updated `.htaccess` file but to no avail. https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8AhQ.png

Comment: @user So, what URL are you requesting? `.htaccess` does not actually "change" the URLs, which sounds as if you are perhaps expecting? If you want the URL to look like `/thankyou/` (note the trailing slash) then you need to be linking to `href="/thankyou/"` in your HTML source.

Comment: Perhaps I am taking the wrong approach. I just want to change the way the URL(s) appear on the client side. The JSON example from the question is exactly what I want to do with a 301 Permanent redirect. When I say re-write I just mean to modify the URL on the client-side. Sorry if my terminology is off.

Comment: @user You can implement an external 301 redirect (as well) in `.htaccess` from `/thankyou.html` to `/thankyou/` (or `/thankyou`), but you must first actually change the URLs in the underlying HTML source code. You then implement a "rewrite" to internally rewrite the URL back again.

Comment: @user I've updated my answer with more explanation and an external redirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251874/discussion-between-user-and-mrwhite).

Comment: Hey, @MrWhite can you invite me to a chat? I have a question for you.